# REST Metadata API is not enabled for this organization?

Tags: metadata-api

[image]

This is a Enterprise Edition org and I can access API urls like `/services/data/v41.0/sobjects/Account/001UHJB000jOJmw` with no issues.

How can I enable this? or Should I contact support for this?

Comment: I hit that issue recently and for the life of me I can't remember what was causing it...

Comment: I think that's a new API that hasn't been fully exposed

Comment: I think it's a v42 feature?

Comment: I tried to make this call from workbench and as well as from Developer console-->Execute Anonymous window in a Unlimited Edition org.... still getting same error .....seems that metadata call is still not available by using REST....

Comment: @javanoob Is this issue solved? I am still facing, any idea?